# are the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I found 8 subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, namely the subgroups generated by each one of its elements. Are there any others? If so, how am I supposed to find all of those that are missing?

Comment: What's the context? Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem, and how it decomposes that group into the product of two smaller groups?

Comment: Yeah, but I heard that it is not true that the subgroups of a direct product are the products of subgroups, so I didn't see how this helps. Maybe this is true under some hypothesis, I don't know.

Comment: That's right, but knowing the structure of the group you're looking at will still be very helpful in finding all its subgroups, even if those subgroups are more numerous than just direct products. For example, it might help you locate a non-cyclic subgroup $\{1,9,11,19\}$....

Comment: Thanks! It is clear that I can find subgroups in the ward way, but I was looking for some kind of algorithm, or at least to know how many subgroups there are, so that I am absolutely sure there is none left, say, for purposes of finding all subfields of a field via Galois correspondence.

Comment: Being at the level where you're learning Galois theory, and looking for an algorithm, are both excellent reasons to understand the subgroup structure of product groups in the first place.